# Django how to use multiple lines with return HttpResponse

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

I just picked up Django a couple days ago and I don't have much experience with any languages other than java, so Python is a bit of a learning curve. I manages to create a web page that generates a random number each time you refresh it and tells you whether or not it is the number one.

[image: current]

The problem lies in using multiple lines on a single page. Instead of having the page look like that, I want it to be formatted vertically, like this:

[image: click]

```
n = random.randint(1, 2)  # returns a random integer
if n == 1:
    query = "The number is One."
else:
    query = "The number Is'nt One."
return HttpResponse(str('Randomly generated number: ') + str(n) + str("   ") + str(query))
```

One thing I noticed is that all the code after "return HttpResponse" is unused, for example if I had moved the "if" and "else" statements to after the HttpResponse, it would be marked as unused code and would not appear on the final product.

Comment: you need html .... `<br>` is newline in html ... its probably time for you to start exploring templates...

Comment: Django can render HTML templates. But hard-coding HTML `<br>` would work also. And sidenote: You don't need to `str()` something that is already a string value like `str("   ")`

Comment: "One thing I noticed is that all the code after "return HttpResponse" is unused"... a return is always the end of a function. When execution of a function hits a return statement you will never run any code that follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn about Python and Django a little more. HttpResponse is a quick and dirty way that output is done in views. You can learn about how use Templates for this, you can read about this in:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial03/

and use Templates for your process.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `<br/>` where you want the break line. When browser finds the `<br/>` changes line.

```
n = random.randint(1, 2)  # returns a random integer
if n == 1:
    query = "The number is one."
else:
    query = "The number isn't one."
return HttpResponse('Random Number Generator <br/> The random number is: ') + str(n) + "<br/>" + query)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution would be to set `content_type="text/plain"`:

```
n = random.randint(1, 2)  # returns a random integer
if n == 1:
    query = "The number is One."
else:
    query = "The number Isn't One."
output_string = "Randomly generated number: \n The random number is: " + str(n) + "\n" + query
return HttpResponse(output_string, content_type="text/plain")
```

The default content type of HttpResponse is `text/html` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#default-content-type)), so using `<br>` would work. However, this essentially creates a non-valid HTML page. Thus, for such simple output, I think `text/plain` is the best choice.